# Can I use splunk timechart without aggregate function?

Tags: splunk

https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.2/SearchReference/Timechart
I tried several syntaxes but none is working. they all require aggregate function.
My goal is to display a line chart, representing the value of an event field over time.
Very simple, I don't need any max/min/sum/count at all.
I need the x-axis to be the time span(time range that I passed in as query timespan), every event will be a data point in that chart, y-axis is the value of a field that I choose, for example, fieldA, which is a double value field.
how to write my splunk query? 
search query ...| timechart fieldA?
(you don't have to use timechart, any command that can achieve my goal will be accepted)

update: let me try to describe what I wanted using a data generation example:
| makeresults count=10 | streamstats count AS rowNumber
let's say the time span is last 24 hours, when running above query in splunk, it will generate 10 records data with the same _time field which is @now, and a rowNumber field with values from 1 to 10. what I want to see is a visualization, x-axis starts from (@now-24hours) to @now, and no data points for most of the x-axis, but at last second(the rightmost) I want to see 10 dots, the y-axis values of them is from 1 to 10.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use an aggregate function with `timechart`.  Just about any `stats` function will do.  See https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.2/SearchReference/Timechart#Stats_function_options.

Depending on the nature of your data and what you want to see in the chart any of `timechart max(fieldA)`, `timechart latest(fieldA)`, `timechart earliest(fieldA)`, or `timechart values(fieldA)` may work for you.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but in my opinion, max/latest/earliest/values(like distinct) are all aggregate functions in a way that they reduced the number from original results. I amended my question by adding an example to describe what I want to see. These functions didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

```
| makeresults count=2
| streamstats count
| eval _time=if(count=1,relative_time(_time,"-1d"),_time)
| timechart span=160min count
| streamstats count
| timechart cont=f last(count)
```

https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Eventorderfunctions

try with time picker `all time`

> they reduced the number from original results.

It depends on how you use it.

Comment: If I am right, you're creating two events, one is 24hr before now, the other is now. Then displaying them in a timechart, which connects the two dots. But linechart is not enough to display my case, my case is in certain point of time, there could be multiple dots and I don't want to aggregate them. so I think I don't need and can't see any lines, my graph is more like dots scattered in time.

Comment: [Line Chart image](https://imgur.com/a/7Q6ACTj)
maybe, your time picker is not `all time`
There is 10 results in _Statistics_ .
I don't have enough karma. link is _imgur.com_

Comment: Yes there are 10 results in my example, and they shared the same _time, so I want to see 10 dots with the same x values, can it be drawn?